# How to hide the ASP.NET_SessionID cookie string in asp.net webform?

Tags: asp.net

How to hide  the ASP.NET_SessionID cookie string or change the `ASP.NET_SessionID` name  in  asp.net webform? TKS!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove this cookie, since it is used by ASP.Net framework internally to identify unique session.

However you can prevent some XSS attacks using `HttpOnly`

```
 ASP.NET_SessionId=ig2fac55; path=/; HttpOnly
```

By default, ASP.Net session cookies are HttpOnly and cannot be modified by client script

**[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)**

> **HttpOnly.** This property specifies whether the cookie can be accessed by client script. In ASP.NET 2.0, this value is always set to
>   true. Internet Explorer 6 Service Pack 1 supports this cookie
>   attribute, which prevents client-side script from accessing the cookie
>   from the document.cookie property. If an attempt is made to access the
>   cookie from client-side script, an empty string is returned. The
>   cookie is still sent to the server whenever the user browses to a Web
>   site in the current domain.